# How to link the installed module in php file?

Tags: php

I'm working in Ubuntu 14.04. I have installed the composer and module is  `namshi/jose`, without any error it was installed. Then I'm trying to link the module in file but it is not working. It is throwing following error.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Namshi\\JOSE\\SimpleJWS' not found in /var/www/html/file.php on line 15
```

In my php code I have include the modules as follow

```
use Namshi\JOSE\SimpleJWS;
```

What should I do for it.? I'm from Perl Background after installing module we simply include `use` in Perl script to call the module.

Comment: You are probably missing a line like this one `require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';` above `use`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell without seeing the contents of `file.php`, but I believe you've forgotten to actually load the composer generated autoloader.

```
require "vendor/autoload.php"
```